# NPN transistor to turn ON an ATTiny85 from a pinout of an ATTiny85

Tags: transistors, npn, attiny, attiny85

I have 2 ATTiny85 and a NPN CS-9011 used as a switch. They are both powered by the same 3.3V. I use pin 1 to run the base of the transistor with a 1K resistor.
This is not working after an afternoon of tests.
I can turn on a sensor, tested with BME280, with this set up but not an ATTiny85.
Should I use another Transistor?
Or can someone show me that the calculation that my Base resistor is wrong?

ATTiny85 Maximum DC Current per I/O Pin 40 mA

[image: ATTiny85 turn on ATTiny85]

[image: CS-9011]

Comment: What is the measured voltage on the switched tiny85? Note that switching 0V aka ‘low side’ is generally avoided as you can have ‘sneak paths’ via the other connected pins.  Eg with the bme280 current can flow back through the I2C or SPI signals.

Comment: I will avoid that then. Yes I suspected that current flowed by another way. I could not find one picture on the net that use an ATTiny85 to control an ATTiny85. I will report in a few days. Thank you

Comment: Here is some measured voltage: I used the the CS91011 on the low side(sorry) and a blue LED with a resistor on pin 3 just to see that the tiny85 on top, in the picture, is up. No sensor and no 1K at the Base(!?). it is working... no smoke. OK voltage up 3.16V and Voltage down 0.62V. This is not what I want of course I want 0V down. Measure is done between VCC and GND pins of the A85 on top.

Comment: When I say working I mean that I see the LED turning ON and OFF which is HIGH when the A85 at the top get 3.16V. (could not edit my previous  comment.)

Comment: Hmm after fooling around with cable and components, top voltage is 2.30V and down is 0.61V and of course the LED does not light anymore. Why did it work before? lot more try and troubleshooting.

Comment: I would recommend a high side p-channel MOSFET. That way you can get the full 3.3 volts of your supply.

Answer (score 1):

Switching power from the GND pin on the ATtiny85 is rather unorthodox way of controlling the supply of a uController but hey, whatever it takes. Perhaps you should consider utilizing a PNP transistor and power the tiny85 with it's collector instead. GND is GND is GND. Some weird things can happen via the other pins of the tiny85 when its GND pin is not tied to GND.

One possible problem may be from the CS9011 that is not bringing the tiny85 GND pin low enough. A transistor that have a max collector current of 30mA is definitely not the best candidate for switching power. If you really insist on this configuration you may want to consider changing the CS9011 for a VN2222 MOSFET. the ON resistance is 7 ohms, surely enough to bring that pin to GND adequately.

Here is another possibility:
[image]

Comment: OK let's change for the collector side and find a MOSFET that match the VN2222 in the land of disappearing component. GND is GND, thank you.

Comment: @pierre  -  If you are not in a hurry check AliExpress or Digikey. The go for less than $1 each

Comment: Only one version on Digikey,  VN2222LL-G-P003 MOSFET N-CH 60V 230MA TO92-3 and If using the collector is the "right" way I will try that first.

Comment: The only 2 MOSFET I could find quickly and get are: FQP27P06 P channel and FQP30N06L N channel and a transistor PNP 2N3906. What ever I did, did not work yet.

Comment: @pierre, Both these MOSFET could work for your application. One doubt I have is about the Vg value (from 2 to 4 V) if you supply the Tiny85 with 3.3v the output of an IO pin may not be sufficient to trigger the MOSFET. The VN2222 show a Gate Threshold of maximum 2.5V, that is more on the safe side for a 3.3V supply ( still low but better than 4V) . Make sure you respect Gate Source and Drain pin configuration.

Comment: FQPs not working. I could not find a VN2222, Digikey shipping is $20 if not mistaken and for AliExpress I do not have the tools nor the knowledge to double check what I would receive. It is working with a 2N2222 on the low side for my case. ON 3.22V, OFF 1.96V. Not what I want but with BOD enabled at 2.7V it does the trick. I might change for power side if I find more information about it. Now I wonder what happen when Tiny85 is in BO mode but the voltage is 1.96. May be I should ask another question.

Comment: ATtiny85 VOL is maximum 0.5V when powered with 3V. VOH is minimum 2.5V. An N MOSFET the gate threshold must be lower than 2.5V. With P MOSFET, its gate threshold must be higher than -2.5V. Voltages are near limits . Perhaps is the reason why it does not work with FQP, the datasheet mention gate threshold between 2.5 up to 4V.  I posted another schematic using PNP 2N3952. Probably many other models may fit the bill. the 2N3952 has a collector current of 200mA and VCE(sat) of max 0.4V which should low enought lost to still permit adequately source enough voltage to power a second ATtiny85.

Comment: Is it really 2N3952? I don't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: My mistake sorry. It is a 2N3962. Here is a link to datasheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XXDd-D-vPiy_mgzsAvPp37aCZ_z-uEaE/view?usp=sharing     .I will update my schematic

Comment: 2N3962 is just an example. Any PNP that can handle 200mA collector current 
 and a decent gain can do the job.  Chances are you may have a unit that will do the job in your scrap box.